# How to create reference to /dev in a chroot jail that is deletion-proof?

Tags: unix, hyperlink, mount, chroot

I need to create a chroot jail for my program. The program needs the contents of /dev to execute properly. I don't want to copy the contents of /dev in the chroot jail, because I want to avoid the duplication of elements in the jail.

I have found 2 solutions to this problem, but none of them are fully solving my problem:

- Mounting /dev: works, but a sys admin can delete /dev if he deletes the chroot jail through "rm -rf". This is bad...
- Symbolic link on /dev: does not work because symbolic links that are pointing outside of the jail do not work.

Do you know a solution that avoids duplication, is secure on deletion and works?

Comment: What's more, you say you want to avoid duplicated elements... Fine, but then do you use only static binaries? Otherwise you won't be able to avoid copying the necessary libraries into your chroot.

Answer (score 1):

On linux :

- You can mount devfs filesystem :
  mount -t devtmpfs none /jail/dev

On freebsd :

- You can mount devfs filesystem :
  mount -t devfs none /jail/dev
- Or for mount a folder (not recommended for dev) :
  mount_nullfs /dev /jail/dev

If you want no duplication, you need to umount before delete the jail.
You can mount in readonly, but you can have problems with softwares (depends of jail use).